# Aweber developer/labs API working

Tags: php, wordpress, aweber

I just created an account on https://labs.aweber.com/apps in order to test Aweber service. I created an app there too.

First,I'm trying to create a list (listname) in my this developer account, I"m not sure how to add a list to it? and can see app id, is this list_id?

Second, I'm trying to access this developer account using my plugin. I have downloaded a PHP library from their labs and it contains demo.php. I have  found Consumer Key & Consumer secret keys from labs, and changed them in my demo.php and when i run demo.php it always takes me to:
https://auth.aweber.com/1.0/oauth/authorize?oauth_token=Aqz6ePpjxPrZ0DePqi3LDBmZ

I'm not user which login to use?

Third, I'm trying to add a subscriber to a list. How can i get accessKey,accessSecret,$account_id for below script?

https://labs.aweber.com/docs/code_samples/subs/create

Aweber's labs documentation are very short, they are not such clear about these things. Please give me your suggestions if any body have used Aweber's labs account for testing. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You also need to have an Aweber account. The developer account just gives you the privileges to create an app and talk to their API.

You then need a regular Aweber account to add subscribers or gets lists.

Comment: yes! developer must buy an account only to build something with Aweber

Comment: @anilviradiya I haven't looked at aweber in years but when I was doing it you must have had a paid account to test it. There is no free aweber account, though there is a trial.